# How to control the memory heap size of Spark History Server?

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-cdh

We have Spark (1.2) running on YARN with CDH 5.3.2, and Spark History Server.

For small jobs history server is able to works, but for few large jobs Spark History Server not able to retrieve logs/job history. and showing following error in

```
  2015-04-09 09:50:48,061 WARN     org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler: Error for /history/application_1428034115331_31584
org.spark-project.guava.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.spark-project.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2261)
at org.spark-project.guava.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
at org.spark-project.guava.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
at org.spark-project.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer$$anon$1.doGet(HistoryServer.scala:85)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
at org.json4s.MonadicJValue$$anonfun$org$json4s$MonadicJValue$$findDirectByName$1.apply(MonadicJValue.scala:26)
at org.json4s.MonadicJValue$$anonfun$org$json4s$MonadicJValue$$findDirectByName$1.apply(MonadicJValue.scala:22)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
at org.json4s.MonadicJValue.org$json4s$MonadicJValue$$findDirectByName(MonadicJValue.scala:22)
at org.json4s.MonadicJValue.$bslash(MonadicJValue.scala:16)
at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.taskInfoFromJson(JsonProtocol.scala:560)
at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.taskEndFromJson(JsonProtocol.scala:465)
at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.sparkEventFromJson(JsonProtocol.scala:425)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ReplayListenerBus$$anonfun$replay$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ReplayListenerBus.scala:71)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ReplayListenerBus$$anonfun$replay$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ReplayListenerBus.scala:69)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ReplayListenerBus$$anonfun$replay$2.apply(ReplayListenerBus.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ReplayListenerBus$$anonfun$replay$2.apply(ReplayListenerBus.scala:55)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ReplayListenerBus.replay(ReplayListenerBus.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider$$anonfun$getAppUI$1.apply(FsHistoryProvider.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider$$anonfun$getAppUI$1.apply(FsHistoryProvider.scala:117)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.getAppUI(FsHistoryProvider.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer$$anon$3.load(HistoryServer.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer$$anon$3.load(HistoryServer.scala:53)
at org.spark-project.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
at org.spark-project.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
at org.spark-project.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
```

I didn't find any way to set heap for spark history server ?
or is this related to YARN History server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

setting SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY=2g in spark-env.sh helped me

Answer (score 3):

I think one of the causes is that the log file is bigger than the daemon memory so that the history server cannot read the whole log into the heap.

You can check the size of the log files in `/tmp/spark-events` if you didn't specify the log directory. Otherwise, go to the specified folder of `spark.eventLog.dir`.

In my case, my log files are about 17g so that I need to set `SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY=20g` in `{SPARK_HOME}/conf/spark.env.sh`.